# Jquery Ajax Call throws undefined error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send two variables to php using a Jquery Ajax call. The call works if async is set to false, but fails when it is true. The code also works when only one variable is input using the form (basically get the response of input missing), however, when both the inputs are given, the code returns an undefined error. Can I get some suggestion please. Struck for quite some time.

Post Edit - I incorporated the changes suggested. The modified code does not work

Here is the Jquery code which I now have -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#callLogin").click(function(){
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = +$("#login_password").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
                data: 'username=' +username + '&login_password='+password,   

        success: function(response){
            if(response!=""){
                alert(response);
                $("#loginErrMsg").html(response);
                $("#myModal").css("display","block");   
            }},
        error : function (ts) {
                    alert(ts.responseStatus);
        }
    });
});
});
```

One more observation: I have also tried serializing the form data and then send it to PHP. Still the only way it seems to work is when I change async: false. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: where is your html ?

Comment: your script looks perfect. please provide html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign something to html you have to put it between brackets.

```
$("#loginErrMsg").html(response);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error out. But the cause of this problem seems to be something else

Comment: Btw you can pass object to "data" and it should work without problems. Why do you change password to integer? If you put "+" before variable it will change your variable to integer. Why do you need to change your password to integer?

Comment: it did not work either by - data: {
    'username': username,
    'login_password':  password
   },

Comment: If you will pass string to "login_password" you will get NaN. Are you sure you have all ids named correctly?

Answer (score 0):

when you want to pass multiple data in ajax call you can pass like i have shown in below code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#callLogin").click(function(){
var username = $("#username").val();
var password = +$("#login_password").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: 'username=' +username + '&login_password='+password,   


        success: function(response){
            if(response!=""){
                alert(response);
                $("#loginErrMsg").html(response);
                $("#myModal").css("display","block");   
            }},
        error : function (ts) {
                    alert(ts.responseStatus);
        }
    });
});
});
```

try this may your problem will solve.

Comment: Thanks it works. But can you please tell me what was wrong with my code. Especially given the fact that it worked when async was set to false.

Comment: Creepy. Your suggestion was working, but when I incorporated the change suggested by Mirr below (which was an obvious error on my part) it again stops working and gives the same errror. I am providing the formatted code once again below.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by referring to a similar problem posted here. Basically needed to set $("#callLogin").click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); .... }. The submit function in the form was getting called twice, which was creating the problem. Thanks for all the help anyways.